# minDate not working on datetimepicker library

Tags: javascript, php, datetimepicker

I use the datetimepicker plugin for datepicker. I want to hide past date from today But mindate not working. I use like this:

```
$('.datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
   onChangeDateTime:logic,
   onShow:logic,
   format:'d/m/Y',
   formatDate:'d/m/Y',
   timepicker:false,
   minDate: +1, // here i use minDate but this is not working
   theme:'dark'
});
```

See image past date is visible on the datepicker box:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I fixed the problem by using:

```
var tday = new Date();

$('.datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
  onChangeDateTime:logic,
  onShow:logic,
  format:'d/m/Y',
  formatDate:'d/m/Y',
  timepicker:false,
  minDate: tday,
  theme:'dark'
});
```